# Values get overwritten by latest person to request the bot?

Tags: node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I have made a raffle ballot discord bot that allows a user to DM the bot their name and raffle entry amount. Once they have set the values they can start the entry of the raffle by DMing !enter. Once this has happend a function is called which then starts a for-loop the for loop will run based on the specified entry amount. I have also added in a delay within the for-loop due to the service to get the raffle tickets takes some time (Code is edited for SO Post due to sensitive API info)

Once this is complete it then sends a DM back to the user that had DMed the bot originally. The problem I am facing is that if multiple users DM at the same time or while it is running from the first DM the variables get overwritten by the latest person requesting the bot.

I assumed that by using a Discord.js bot each time a user DMs it creates a new instance of the script or node process?

Is it possible for the function that the bot calls once DMed to create a new process within the main node process so it doesn't get overwritten?

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const botconfig = require('./discordBotConfig.json');
const bot = new Discord.Client({disableEveryone: true});
const c = require('chalk');

// Chalk Theme
const ctx = new c.constructor({level: 2});
const error = c.red;
const waiting = c.magenta;
const success = c.green;
const discordBot = c.yellow;

// Current Raffles (API Link Later)
let activeRaffles = 'Raffle 1';

// User Parmas
let usrName = '';
let entryAmount = 0;

// Ticket
let raffleTicket = [];
let retryDelay = 3000;

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

// Enter
const enterIn = async () => {
    console.log('User name', usrName);
    raffleTicket.push(Math.random(0, 50));
}

// Init Raffle Entry
const raffleInit = async (entryAmount) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < entryAmount; i++) {
        enterIn();
        await sleep(retryDelay);
    }
    dmUser();
}

const dmUser = () => {
    // Discord Message Complete
    let botCompleteMsg = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle('Finished!')
    .setColor('#25E37A')
    .addField('Name: ', usrName)
    .addField('Tickets: ', raffleTicket)
    .addField('Last Update: ', bot.user.createdAt);

    bot.fetchUser(userID).then((user) => {
        user.send(botCompleteMsg);
    });

    return; // End the application
}

// Discord Bot Setup
bot.on('ready', async () => {
    console.log(discordBot(`${bot.user.username} is Online!`));
    bot.user.setActivity('Entering Raffle');
});

bot.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.channel.type === 'dm') {

    let prefix = botconfig.prefix;
    let messageArray = message.content.split(' ');

    let cmd = messageArray[0];
        if (cmd === `${prefix}name`) {
            if (messageArray.length === 3) {
                userID = message.author.id;
                usrName = messageArray[1];
                entryAmount = messageArray[2];

                // Raffle summary
                let raffleSummary = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setTitle('Entry Summary')
                .setColor('#8D06FF')
                .addField('Name: ', usrName)
                .addField('Entry Amount: ', entryAmount)
                return message.author.send(raffleSummary), message.author.send('Type **!start** to begin entry or type **!set** again to set the entry details again.');
            }
        }

        if (cmd === `${prefix}enter`) {
            // Raffle summary
            let startMessage = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setTitle('Entering raffle!')
            .setDescription('Thanks for entering! :)')
            .setColor('#8D06FF')
            return message.author.send(startMessage), raffleInit(entryAmount);
        }

    }
});

bot.login(botconfig.token);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store your user data in a list with classes.

```
var userData = [
{name: "sample#0000", entryNum: 0}
];
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.